# Callback inside Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a doubt in using Promise.all. I need to have three functions with callbacks. So I am writing these three function inside Promise.all and then get all three functions result in .then() of Promise.all. Is it a proper way or is there any other way?

Comment: Can't be 100% sure without seeing the code, but if they're promisified properly, that sounds perfect

Comment: Code or it didn't happen...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're doing it right, yes; it would have been better if you'd shown code.

But let's say you want to start three processes, which are started by `doThis()`, `doThat()`, and `doTheOther()`. You handle it like this:

```
Promise.all([
    doThis(),
    doThat(),
    doTheOther()
])
.then(([thisResult, thatResult, theOtherResult]) => { // The destructuring is optional, of course
    // ...use them...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Key bits:

1. You pass an iterable to `Promise.all` (I used an array above)
2. You receive the results in the same order as the iterable (regardless of what order things completed in)
3. `Promise.all`'s promise rejects if *any* of the operations rejects.

---

In a comment you've posted this code:

```
Promise.all([
    client.query(q1,function(err,res){ dosomething();}),
    client.query(q2,function(err,res){ dosomething();})
])
.then(() => {
    dosomething()};
})  // <== Added missing }
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // <== Added missing ;
}); // <== Added missing ;
```

That looks incorrect. Normally, when a function accepts a callback like you show `query` doing, it doesn't return a promise. Check your documentation for the `query` call you're making.

**If** it returns a promise, then you'd use it like this:

```
Promise.all([
    client.query(q1).then(dosomething),
    client.query(q2).then(dosomething)
])
.then(() => {
    dosomething()};
})  // <== Added missing }
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // <== Added missing ;
}); // <== Added missing ;
```

...assuming you want `doSomething` to be called only when the query succeeds (your code was calling it whether the query succeeded or failed).

If `query` doesn't return a promise, you'd wrap it in something that does, like this:

```
function doQuery(client, q) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.query(q, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

then using that:

```
Promise.all([
    doQuery(client, q1).then(doSomething),
    doQuery(client, q2).then(doSomething)
])
.then(() => {
    dosomething()};
})  // <== Added missing }
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // <== Added missing ;
}); // <== Added missing ;
```

(Again, I've assumed `doSomething` should only be called when the query was successful.)

These days, lots of APIs are adding promise features. Also, there's [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to wrap callback-style API functions in promises. Here's how you'd use that with your code

```
const doQuery = util.promisify(client.query.bind(client)); // Note the .bind(client)
Promise.all([
    doQuery(q1).then(doSomething),
    doQuery(q2).then(doSomething)
])
.then(() => {
    dosomething()};
})  // <== Added missing }
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // <== Added missing ;
}); // <== Added missing ;
```

Comment: I am giving a sample as follows. Promise.all([ client.query(q1,function(err,res){ dosomething();}),client.query(q2,function(err,res){ dosomething();})]).then(()=>{ dosomething()};).catch(e=>{console.log(e)})

Comment: @kaitlyn - Code in comments doesn't work well, as you can see. :-) If you want to show the code you're using, best to use the "edit" link on the question.

Comment: @kaitlyn - ...but that code looks incorrect. If `query` accepts a callback, usually that means it's not promise-based. I've updated the answer to address that code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the callbacks in a promise to resolve them all with Promise.all

So:

```
Promise.all([
    new Promise(resolve => client.query(q1, function(err, result) { resolve(result); }) ),
    new Promise(resolve => client.query(q2, function(err, result) { resolve(result); }) ),
    new Promise(resolve => client.query(q3, function(err, result) { resolve(result); }) )
]).then(([q1, q2, q3]) => {
   //do something with results
}).
```

If you need to handle errors you'll need to reject on error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: 1. Doing this inline is generally error prone; instead, create a wrapper function. 2. That code ignores the possibility that the query failed. It should check `err` and branch accordingly.

Comment: As I said, if you need to handle errors then you can reject

Comment: Why show incorrect code? Why not just show it correctly?